# Including and automatically compiling Sass on Express server

Tags: node.js, express, sass

So I have a basic Express project set up and I'm using this github project, https://github.com/andrew/node-sass, to be able to use Sass on top of node. This is my `app.js` currently:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    jquery = require('jquery');


/**
* Create app
*/

var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

/**
* Configure app
*/ 

app.configure(function(){ 
    app.set('port', 8080);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

What do I need to do to get Sass working and auto recompiling? I can't seem to find any useful info for Express servers specifically.

Comment: I would only use this approach if it's actually pre-compiling your styles before the app is run. If it does not do that, I would avoid using this solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First add this `require` statement:

```
var sass = require("node-sass");
```

and then the following code, in your `app.configure` block:

```
...
app.use(sass.middleware({
    src: <your-sass-files-dir>,
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    debug: true
}));
...
```

**But** I'm sorry to say that the node-sass library is quite **useless** at the moment, because the `@import`'s, in your `scss` files, does not work as it's supposed to... See https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/27 for current status.

**UPDATE 2013-10-22:** Apparently the issue mentioned above seems to be fixed according to [@jonathanconway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855553/including-and-automatically-compiling-sass-on-express-server#comment28939341_13895264) in the comments below... Though there's still an [unanswered comment on the issue from someone that still experiences the error at 2013-09-03](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/27#issuecomment-23705634)

Comment: So I should use LESS or Stylus?

Comment: Personally I prefer SASS with the SCSS syntax over both LESS and Stylus, mostly because of the great framework http://inuitcss.com/.
So I would recommend to keep using SASS, but compile it with the ruby-gem sass. That's what I'll do until node-sass, or another package will get good enough...

Comment: The import issues seem to have been fixed, as import now works fine for me (at least, on WinServer 2008).

Comment: Nice, to hear that! I think SASS is great, but have found myself using stylus in all of my NodeJS work instead, since this issue, so maybe now I'm ready to go back :)

Answer (score 0):

Like joakimbeng said, currently the node-sass library has an issue where the `@import`'s are kind of broken.

However! I found a workaround, which [you can see here](https://github.com/branneman/frontend-bootstrap/blob/master/server.js#L13-24).

What I did basically is grab the raw sass (in my case, scss), and let node-sass render the string for me. But, since it's *current working directory* is wherever your server.js file is located, you're going to have to put url's in your sass file, relative to your server.js. In my case, [like this](https://github.com/branneman/frontend-bootstrap/blob/master/src/static/css/all.scss).